# "Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined" error comes when compiling java script?

Tags: javascript, html

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

     var hamburger = $(".hamburger");
     var line = $(".line");
     var menuOpen;

     function openMenu() //function used to open menu
     {
       menu.css("left", "0px");
       line.css("background", "#FFF");
       menuOpen = true;
      }

       function closeMenu() //closing the menu
      {
       menu.css("left", "-320px");
       line.css("background", "#BCAD90");
       menuOpen = false;
       }

       function toggleMenu(){ // toggle between opening ang closing menu
        if (menuOpen){
         closeMenu();
       } 
       else 
       {
        openMenu();
       }
       }

       hamburger.on({      //hamburger menu
        mouseenter: function(){
       openMenu();
       }
      });

      menu.on({  
       mouseleave: function(){
      closeMenu();
      }

      });

      hamburger.on({
       click: function(){
      toggleMenu();
      }
      })


     });
```

Above is the code snippet for both Javascript and HTML files, but after compiling the above code it shows the error message in the browser as `"Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined"`.kindly resolve this error and suggest the necessary solution.

Comment: you need to add jquery in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser is unable to load JQuery library.
It seems like you have missed the script for loading it.

Embed the following in your index.html

```
<script
 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: But I'm getting the same error here is the code snippet for HTML.                       <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
   <title> &#9834; EuroMusic &reg; </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="Euromusic.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Euromusic.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>

Comment: <body>
  <script language="javascript" >
  </script>
 <div class="hamburger">
  <div class='line'></div>
  <div class='line'></div>
  <div class='line'></div>
 </div>
 <div class='menu'>
  <div class='menu-item'>Home</div>
  <div class='menu-item'>About</div>
  <div class='menu-item'>Contact</div>
 </div> 
 <section>
  <h1> Welcome to EuroMusic </h1>
  <h5> Listen to latest track hits of 2017 </h5>
 </section>
</body>
</html>

Comment: and stylesheet detailsbody 
{
  background: #DDD8D5;
  color: #91966E;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h1,h5 {
font-weight: 100;
}

Comment: section {
 background: #E4E4E6;
 padding: 6rem 3rem;
 margin: 0;
}

.hamburger {
 position: absolute;
 margin: 6px;
 z-index:2;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.line {
 width: 50px;
 height: 6px;
 background: #BCAD90;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.menu {
 width: 320px;
 height: 100%;
 background: #BCAD90;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: -320px;
 transition: left .1s;
}

.menu-item:first-child {
 margin-top: 180px;
}

.menu-open {
 left: 0;
}

.menu-item {
 color: #fff;
 width: 100px;
 padding: 1rem 3rem;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

Comment: If you see in your code snippet
The code to load your file i.e. 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Euromusic.js">
is before 
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"; integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt‌​4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Since the browser interprets the code line by line, it first parses your file and then loads jQuery.

Solution: Move the code to load jquery before the code where your file is being loaded.